# From the below json data how can I print the tlds using foreach loop in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Find below my `json` data and suggest me how to print the tld using `foreach` loop in `laravel`. Suggest me how to declare this array structure using `foreach` loop.

```
 {
   "result": "success",
       "currency": {
       "id": "1",
       "code": "INR",
       "prefix": " \u20b9",
       "suffix": "INR",
       "format": "1",
       "rate": "1.00000"
        },
       "pricing": {
        "in": {
        "categories": [
        "ccTLD",
        "Geography"
       ],
      "addons": {
        "dns": true,
        "email": true,
        "idprotect": true
      },
      "group": "",
      "register": {
        "1": "704.39"
      },
      "transfer": {
        "1": "704.39"
      },
      "renew": {
        "1": "704.39"
      }
    },
    "in.net": {
      "categories": [
        "Other"
      ],
      "addons": {
        "dns": true,
        "email": true,
        "idprotect": true
      },
      "group": "",
      "register": {
        "1": "547.69"
      },
      "transfer": {
        "1": "547.69"
      },
      "renew": {
        "1": "547.69"
      }
    },
    "info": {
      "categories": [
        "gTLD",
        "Popular"
      ],
      "addons": {
        "dns": true,
        "email": true,
        "idprotect": true
      },
      "group": "",
      "register": {
        "1": "861.10"
      },
      "transfer": {
        "1": "861.10"
      },
      "renew": {
        "1": "861.10"
      }
    },
    "org": {
      "categories": [
        "gTLD",
        "Popular"
      ],
      "addons": {
        "dns": true,
        "email": true,
        "idprotect": true
      },
      "group": "",
      "register": {
        "1": "939.45"
      },
      "transfer": {
        "1": "939.45"
      },
      "renew": {
        "1": "939.45"
      }
    },
    "com": {
      "categories": [
        "gTLD",
        "Popular"
      ],
      "addons": {
        "dns": true,
        "email": true,
        "idprotect": true
      },
      "group": "",
      "register": {
        "1": "740.43"
      },
      "transfer": {
        "1": "740.43"
      },
      "renew": {
        "1": "740.43"
      }
    },
    "net": {
      "categories": [
        "gTLD",
        "Popular"
      ],
      "addons": {
        "dns": true,
        "email": true,
        "idprotect": true
      },
      "group": "",
      "register": {
        "1": "829.76"
      },
      "transfer": {
        "1": "829.76"
      },
      "renew": {
        "1": "829.76"
      }
    },
    "biz": {
      "categories": [
        "gTLD",
        "Popular"
      ],
      "addons": {
        "dns": true,
        "email": true,
        "idprotect": true
      },
      "group": "",
      "register": {
        "1": "878.33"
      },
      "transfer": {
        "1": "878.33"
      },
      "renew": {
        "1": "878.33"
      }
     }
    }
    }
```

From the above data I wanted to display the tlds such as **in,in.net,org,info,com,net,biz**.

Comment: which laravel version you are using.

Comment: we are using laravel 5.6

Comment: I'm getting an error as illegal offset string . Please suggest me a solution to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```php
$tlds = array_keys(json_decode($json, true)['pricing']);
```